# Titanium mobile restart application fix implementation

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I found a fix to an issue of android restart application bug but I cant see the way to implement it. What is the file to edit under windows xp? Here is the fix http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4941

maybe someone could help with that? Thank you.

Comment: Please find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16850888/1468354)

Answer (score 0):

The alert saying that an "Application restart is required" *is* the fix. The link you have there describes a bug in Android that would cause a duplicate root activity to exist when the app launches. Titanium is using this forced restart as a workaround for that.

I agree that it's awful, but it's a necessary evil until a proper fix is released.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the following properties:

```
<property name="ti.android.bug2373.disableDetection" type="bool">false</property>
<property name="ti.android.bug2373.restartDelay" type="int">500</property>
<property name="ti.android.bug2373.finishDelay" type="int">0</property>
<property name="ti.android.bug2373.skipAlert" type="bool">false</property>
<property name="ti.android.bug2373.message">An application restart is required</property>
<property name="ti.android.bug2373.title">Restart Required</property>
<property name="ti.android.bug2373.buttonText">Continue</property>
```

skipAlert = true does not display a Toast Message.

I don't know if it works but it's a Titanium fix.