# Ti Android: "Application Restart is required" Error on installing App on Android device

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

After deploying the project build on mobile device, when it is launched from the installer/market, it always gives alert that "Application Restart is required".

I have learnt that this is a very known bug and also that it is an android bug. I have gone through the solution given at (http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4941). I have added the tags mentioned on that page and after that I have tried cleaning the project, deleting the build folder but could not get the problem resolved. My tiapp.xml would look like [this](http://pastie.org/3287079) after adding the bug2373 tags.
Kindly let me know if I am doing anything wrong or I am missing something. Any other workaround would also be helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: usually this happens to me after I install a new database for the App. (beter yet, every time I install a new database) What exactly are you doing in the app?

Comment: Even my application deals with database. I use `var db = Ti.Database.install('/common/appDatabase.db', 'appDatabase');` to install database as this gets executed only at the time of installing the app (as per documentation). Apart from database the application majorly deals ajax calls.

Comment: Hmm than that cannot cause the issue...  Also the issue at JIRA which you linked to is not relevant. There is probably something in your code which causes this...

Comment: Well the behavior of the application is same as bug2373. Meaning it happens only when the application is launched from android market, installer or searchbar. If the application is launched from the app drawer or desktop, it launches correctly. I am not sure if this behavior has anything to do with code. My Application majorly deals with database and network. Apart from that only UI elements are present. Out of these three which one could be suspicious? That would help in narrowing down the investigation.

Comment: The only thing that can be suspicious is the database handling.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Titanium, though they have fixed it.
Please add following line to **tiapp.xml**

```
<property name="ti.android.bug2373.finishfalseroot" type="bool">true</property>
```